# Android: Set Circular progressbar at the center of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar

Progress bar is appearing at the top center of the layout but i want to align it at the center of the layout. I have also tried other answers on Stackoverflow but it didn't work. Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Bansal read question. He already applied that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Comment: layout_height="match_parent" in recyclerview worked well. Thanks man!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Make your `recyclerview` visibility as gone previously when you are fetching data and after you fetch data then set `progressbar` visibility as gone and `recyclerview` visibility as visible

Comment: i already tried centerInParent="true" in relativelayout but it's still not working

Comment: @Androidjack is your layout is main layout or it is child of some other  layout. Because how it is possible that it's working perfect on my device

Comment: it is a fragment layout..anyway thanks a lot but layout_height="match_parent" worked.

Comment: @Androidjack what is difference between accepted answer and my answer?

Comment: i already specified in the comment .changing recyclerview's layout height to match_parent worked for me.

Comment: @Androidjack It really doesn't matter. Anyways Happy coding  :)